# How to get coordinates from second point given the coordinates from first point, distance between them and angle

Tags: analytic-geometry, geodesy

I have a Point P1 with the coordinates P(405747|5725660) in KBS EPSG:25832.
Now I want to get the coordinates of a second Point P2. P2 is exactly 10m away from P1 and 30° from North.

[image]

Sorry for the bad drawing but I think it's clear what I mean. How do I get the coordinates of P2? For P(X2/Y2) is Y2 = Y1 + length * sin(Alpha). But what is the length? It can't be 10 can it? I feel that I need to convert the Meter into a different unit.

Not sure which Tags to use... but hope they are fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P_1$ has coordinates
$$
(x_1, y_1)
$$
in metres (which is what https://epsg.io/25832 says are the units), 
and your drawing is correct so that the angle is measured *clockwise* from north (which I'm assuming is your $y$-axis, with the $x$-axis pointing to the right), and the distance is $10$ metres, then (because the distance is so small), we have
$$
P_2 = (x_2, y_2)
$$
where
\begin{align}
x_2 &= x_1 + 10 \cdot \sin(30)\\
y_2 &= y_1 + 10 \cdot \cos(30)\\
\end{align}
where the sine and cosine are taken in degrees rather than the usual radians. Using 3-digit approximations for each of these, we get
\begin{align}
x_2 &= x_1 + 10 \cdot 0.500 = x_1 + 5.000\\
y_2 &= y_1 + 10 \cdot 0.866 = y_1 + 8.66\\
\end{align}

In your case, the starting point has $(x_1, y_1) = (405747, 5725660)$, so that 
$$
(x_2, y_2) = (4057\color{red}{52}, 572566\color{red}{8.66})
$$
where I've colored the changed digits in red.

Two things to note: 
1. The earth's surface is curved, and for large distances, it's possible that the coordinate system's intrinsic distortions will cause the "everything is planar" approximation I've used here to be wrong. At a scale of 10 meters, however, it's surely correct to at least a couple of decimal points.

2. It's really easy to get things wrong in situations like this by not noting all your assumptions. I've assumed that

   a. your starting point is measured in metres (because that's what the reference said),

   b. that "up" on the page is the $+y$ axis,

   c. that "right" on the page is the $+x$ axis,

   d. that angles are measured clockwise from the $+y$ axis

   e. that angle measurements are in degrees

The first item could be wrong if you're using a different reference than I am. The second and third "seem obvious", but they're not correct for the usual coordinate on a page of paper (where $x$ goes to the right and $y$ goes down, for instance, in Postscript). The fourth seems obvious from your drawing, but one should never assume, and the fifth is just a guess because you seem to be messing with navigation/geodesy/GIS stuff, where degrees are common.

Comment: thanks a lot John! I really appreciate your detailed explanation, it helped me a lot. Oh and all your assumtions were right.

Comment: I'm glad the assumptions are right. If you end up asking further questions, then *stating* those assumptions as part of the question will save your answerers the work of trying to guess what you meant, which is a generous thing to do, and will get you better answers sooner. (Of course, sometimes we make assumptions that we don't even notice, and failing to note those is perfectly OK -- you'll get comments asking things like "Did you REALLY mean that $n$ should be an integer value rather than an arbitrary real number?")

Comment: Yes, and actually when I posed the question I thought the assumptions are obvious. Only after I read your comment I realized that I could have been more specific.